# Libre Office Writer - How to get a floating formula?

Tags: libreoffice

I use a lot of formulas in Libre Office Writer which I create with the formula editor. Sometimes, I want to move a formula around freely and position it anywhere, similar to what I can do with an image which I insert.

I tried to insert a text box and put the formula inside but unfortunately, this doesn't work. Does anybody know of another way?

Comment: Close voters: Really? Simple problem simple answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I know of is placing the formula in a spreadsheet in LibreOffice calc and simply copy and paste the cell into your Writer document. Then you can drag it wherever you want.

Another way is to simply right-click the object, Select Anchor and choose  `To page` which will allow you to drag it around anywhere on the page.

Comment: +1 for changing the anchor.  However, the answer could be simplified.  Right-click on formula and specify `Anchor-> To Page`.  Done!

Comment: @JimK you are correct. Editing